# Jquery select next text input value

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have got  dynamic checkboxes along with corresponding text input's. What I'm trying to achieve is when a checkbox is checked that particular checkbox text input's value is alerted. I can't seem to get the value of the text input. At the moment all the checkboxes alert the value of the first textbox only instead of the right one. Also by default the text inputs should be hidden until a checkbox is clicked, which then shows the respective text field

http://jsfiddle.net/hpJMN/55/

Above is a simple example of what Im trying  to achieve.

```
 <h3>Checkbox Toggle input element</h3>


<div class="equipment">

</div>


printarr();
```

Script

```
$(".equipment input:checkbox").change(function () {
    alert($(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val());
});

function printarr() {
    for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        $(".equipment").append(
            '<input type="checkbox" name="drill_eq[]" value="' + x + '">&nbsp;' + (x + 1) + '&nbsp<br>' + '<input type="text" name="qty" id="' + (x + 1) + '" title="Qty needed" size="1" maxlength="2"><br>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line from this:

```
alert($(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val());
```

to this:

```
alert($(this).nextAll("input[type=text]").first().val());
```

The key difference is to use **nextAll** instead of sibling.  The "siblings" method will find all siblings (before and after) while nextAll will find all siblings after the selected elements (which is what you want).

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your selector to probably somethign like this based on your markup, siblings will select all of your input fields (that are siblings) and you are doing an `eq(0)` which will get only the value of the first one (event with out `eq(0)` you will still only the value of the first one):

```
$(this).next().next().val();
```

or

```
$(this).nextUntil('input[type=text]').next().val(); //If you are not sure how many other elements may come in between these
```

or

```
$(this).nextAll('input[type=text]').first().val(); //If you are not sure how many other elements may come in between these
```

or

```
$(this).nextAll('input[type=text]:first').val();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mq5cF/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 alert($(this).nextAll("input:text").get(0).value);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/njpXL/)**